# SQL Deployment Bicep MS Entra Group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, cicd, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I want to use bicep to deploy sql server in my resource group and assign entra group as admin. Following which there is also a dacpac deployment task. Every time I try I either get "Invalid value given for parameter Login" or "Invalid value given for parameter Password"

Here is the template

```
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  name: 
  location: 
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: ''
    administratorLoginPassword: guid()
    minimalTlsVersion: '1.2'
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
      principalType: 'Group'
      login: sqlServerLoginName
      sid: sqlServerGroupObjectId
      tenantId: subscription().tenantId
      azureADOnlyAuthentication: true
    }
    version: '12.0'
  }
  identity:{
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

resource sqlServerDatabase 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2021-11-01' = {
  parent: sqlServer
  name: 
  location: 
  sku: 
  properties: {
    maxSizeBytes: 1073741824
  }
}

resource sqlServerAdminResource 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/administrators@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  parent: sqlServer
  name: 'ActiveDirectory'
  properties: {
        administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
        login: sqlServerLoginName
        sid: sqlServerGroupObjectId
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    }  
}


resource sqlServerAzureAdOnly 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/azureADOnlyAuthentications@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  name: ''
  parent: sqlServer
  properties: {
    azureADOnlyAuthentication: true
  }
  dependsOn:[sqlServerAdminResource ]
}
```

Dacpac deployment task for reference

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
        displayName: Deploy DB
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 
          AuthenticationType: servicePrincipal
          ServerName: '***.database.windows.net'
          DatabaseName: ''
          deployType: 'DacpacTask'
          DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
          DacpacFile: '***\Database.dacpac'
          AdditionalArguments: ''
          IpDetectionMethod: 'IPAddressRange'
          StartIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
          EndIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
          DeleteFirewallRule: true
```

I have tried multiple variations which are recommended but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: is the bicep deployment that fails or the dacpac task ?

Comment: the bicep template sounds right, you dont need the `sqlServerAdminResource` resource as you already define the sql admin group in the `sqlServer ` resource

Comment: what is the value of the `sqlServerLoginName` param ? should be the display name of the group in MS Entra. `sqlServerGroupObjectId` shoudb be the objectid of the group in MS Entra as well

Comment: also can you confirm the service principal you are using is in the sql admin group ?

Comment: @Thomas 1. Bicep deployment fails on deploying main bicep not on dacpac  2. Yes, I do not need to define at both places, I think I shared a version where I was trying a couple of things forgot to comment it out 3. Yes I have the Entra group name as the login name and its object id as sqlServerGroupObjectId, there was a suggestion in one of the blogs/stackoverflow link that suggested it should be something else than the actual group name but that failed too 4. I will confirm the service principal soon

Comment: Yes the service principal is part of the group I am trying to make admin

Comment: Ho sorry I did not read properly but you don't have to define `administratorLogin` and `administratorLoginPassword` => just remove these properties from your bicep file

Comment: ok so I will remove that and also not have sqlServerAdminResource separately since it is part of sqlServer properties and give it a shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256395/discussion-between-lucky-and-thomas).

Comment: @Thomas I have posted a message in chat, please let me know your opinion

Comment: @Thomas Your suggestion is working so you can post it as an answer and I will accept it, however I have one variation which I have posted in chat. Please confirm

Comment: let me have a look at it. its late where i am ^^ will keep you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template looks good but you need to:

- remove the `sqlServerAdminResource` resource as it s not needed
- remove the `administratorLogin` and `administratorLoginPassword` properties from the `sqlServer` resource as you specified `azureADOnlyAuthentication: true`

Answer (score 0):

> Fails on deployment with: Server active directory administrator type should be ActiveDirectory (Code: InvalidServerAdministratorTypePropertyName):

Thanks [@Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167200/thomas) for your inputs on the above issue. After going through the discussion in the comment section, I added below workaround which would resolve your issue.

You need to add [`Microsoft.Sql/servers/azureADOnlyAuthentications`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/azureadonlyauthentications?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) to deploy the SQL server with only `AzureADOnly` authentication. Refer the code below.

```bash
param administratorLogin string = 'roots'
param administratorLoginPassword string = 'xxxx'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  name: 'sqlserverjah'
  location: location
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: administratorLogin
    administratorLoginPassword: administratorLoginPassword
  }
}

resource sqlAdminsResource 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/administrators@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  parent: sqlServer
  name: 'sqlserverName-ActiveDirectory'
  properties: {
    administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
    login: administratorLogin
    sid: 'xxxx'
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
  }
}

resource AzureAdOnly 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/azureADOnlyAuthentications@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  name: 'Default'
  parent: sqlServer
  properties: {
    azureADOnlyAuthentication: true
  }
  dependsOn: [sqlAdminsResource]
}
```

[image]

Comment: I do have this, if you see the bicep shared in my question and in chat but it fails